# Strange error when declaring a variable in C# using VS13

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So I have the office library imported, I say `using Microsoft.Office.Interop;`

I am trying to create a method that checks to see if an Excel workbook is open. Havent made any progress yet, because of this error.

when I declare `Excel.Application exApp;` it says the Type or Namespace name'excel' could not be found.

it says that I need to declare it saying `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application exApp;`

I really don't think that I did anything wrong here... There is no error on my import..

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;

namespace Month_End_Closing
{
    public partial class Step1Form : Form
    {
        public Step1Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        static bool IsOpened(string wbook)
        {
            bool isOpened = true;
            Excel.Application exApp;

            return isOpened;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to the appropriate assembly?

Comment: @JonSkeet:  If he didn't have the reference, wouldn't he get the error on the `using Microsoft.Office.Interop` statement?

Comment: @AlexFarber I have added it... did you not read the post...

Comment: @TonyVitabile thats why I am a bit confused.

Comment: @TonyVitabile: Not necessarily - there could be a *different* assembly contributing to that namespace (e.g. one for Word, but not Excel).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`using` directives don't work like that. You can't provide *part* of a namespace name in the `using` directive, and then the rest elsewhere.

From section 9.4.2 of the C# 5 specification:

> A *using-namespace-directive* imports the types contained in a namespace into the immediately enclosing compilation unit or namespace body, enabling the identifier of each type to be used without qualification.
>
> ...
>
> A *using-namespace-directive* imports the types contained in the given namespace, but specifically does not import nested namespaces.

For example, this is invalid:

```
using System;
...

Console.WriteLine(IO.File.Exists("foo"));
```

So you could write:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

and then:

```
Application exApp;
```

assuming that `Application` is otherwise unambiguous. (It sounds like it's not in your case.) Or you could use an alias:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

and then:

```
Excel.Application exApp;
```

Comment: So I am still confused now as to why I can't say `using Microsoft.Office.Interop` and then declare say `Excel.Application`. By the same logic Isn't that equivalent to `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` then `Application`?

Comment: @metsales: No, it's not. Because `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` is a complete namespace name. A `using` directive lists the namespaces in which to look for types... it's not providing some sort of hierarchy.

Comment: Actually, your syntax DOES NOT work either. And by the error I am getting it has to be done using an alias. Because I get an ambiguous reference between `Forms.Application` and `Excel.Application`. I know back when I was doing this in VB I was declaring with `Excel.Application` with no issues

Comment: @metsales: Your sample code didn't have a `using` directive for `System.Windows.Forms`, so there's no ambiguity there. You can't expect me to react to code which you haven't provided... If you need to resolve the ambiguity, use the alias approach at the bottom of the answer. I've edited the answer to include a specification reference which spells this out further btw.

Comment: (sorry about that -- I didn't think the question warranted listing the 12 other imports I have...) The alias works perfectly actually. Would this be a "proper" way of doing it : `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` or is that a bit sloppy?

Comment: @metsales: I'd just use the form I've given before - that way it's clear that it's the `Application` type, and also that it's `Excel`. You could have `using ExcelApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` if you want to be slightly shorter - but then you'd still need to think about any other types in the same namespace.